# Unable to push object to model with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, belongs-to, ruby-on-rails-5.2

After upgrading to Rails 5.2 from Rails 4, I've got some issues with model associations.

I have a model Event that has users as a members of event, and each Event has one Reserve for users that want to attend later.

```
# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord

  # Events has many Users through subcsriptions
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_one :reserve
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions

  ...

end
```

Reserve model:

```
# app/models/reserve.rb
class Reserve < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event, optional: true
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

Subscription model:

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :reserve
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I'm trying to push user to reserve OR event:

```
@event.users << current_user
```

i've got that error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Reserve must exist):
```

Why Reserve is required for validation? It's obvious that Reserve IS optional.

Comment: Show your `Subscription` model also .

Comment: It's not obvious that reserve is optional.  How is rails supposed to know that?  You need to state that it's optional explicitly: `has_one :reserve, optional: true`

Comment: `has_one :model, optional: true` is not a valid key in rails 5.2
and.... `has_one :reserve, validate: false` has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Reserve must exist)

You can use `optional: true` in the `belongs_to` like below to avoid the error.

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :reserve, optional: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I definately forgot about join model!